# How do I scrape the names of these bars from google?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape the names of bars in Hong Kong central from this link:
[link](https://www.google.com/search?q=bar%20hong%20kong%20central&biw=1246&bih=714&sz=0&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALeKk00-T5bIiw3gGOcGpwu5Y1xzOXJngA%3A1621872046866&ei=rs2rYOSsNMX_-Qak8J-ACg&oq=bar+hong+kong+central&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i22i30k1l3.756.1816.0.2125.8.8.0.0.0.0.108.735.6j2.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.733...0j0i13i5i30k1.0.c2k_FF_ybkk&tbs=lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e16!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9&rlst=f#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:%5B%5B22.2885662,114.1597919%5D,%5B22.2800062,114.1517111%5D%5D;tbs:lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e16!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9)

however, I am unable to scrape the data using the class = 'dbg0pd' attribute.

code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bars = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=bar%20hong%20kong%20central&biw=1246&bih=714&sz=16&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALeKk02B3dHjl422M1wOkUldNgdUeC6RVA%3A1621869556252&ei=9MOrYMzsDobZ-QbhyK6YDA&oq=bar+hong+kong+central&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.2313.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.vxIZeVhM24g&tbs=lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e16!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9&rlst=f#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:[[22.287261599999997,114.1668826],[22.2769662,114.1507584]];tbs:lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e16!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9'
info = requests.get(bars)
soup = BeautifulSoup(info.text, "lxml")
soup.select('.dbg0pd')
```

The code returns an empty list [], and I've tried some other classes too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps is a Javascript-driven website, in order to make it work with `BS4` you need to parse `window.APP_INITIALIZATION_STATE` (view source code of the page) variable block using a regular expression to find what you're looking for.

`BeautifulSoup` can't scrape dynamic websites. That was the reason why you were getting an empty `list` because in response there was no such class you were looking for.

To make it work, you can use `selenium` library which is browser automation:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

# Opens URL
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=central+hong+kong+bar')
# Clicks on the "Maps" view in Google Search, clicks on it and turns up on google maps
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hdtb-msb"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a').click()

# Now, this part is akward but very simple. There's a better solution using a while loop.
# Locates first bar
element_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a')
# Scrolls down to the "end" from the first bar
element_container.send_keys(Keys.END)
# Sleep for 3 sec until other bars are loaded
time.sleep(3)
# Scrolls down to the "end" again
element_container.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(3)
# Scrolls down to the "end" again
element_container.send_keys(Keys.END)

# Locates CSS selector for name and prints it
for names in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.qBF1Pd-haAclf'):
    print(names.text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Quinary
The Old Man
The Envoy
COA
001
ROOM 309
HONI HONI Tiki Cocktail Lounge
ORIGIN gin bar
The Iron Fairies Hong Kong
Stockton
Tell Camellia Cocktail Bar
The Pontiac
Frank's Library
Dr. Fern's Gin Parlour
Wahtiki Island Lounge
Draft Land HK
The Wise King
The Diplomat Hong Kong
Karma Lounge
Geronimo Shot Bar HK
```

Alternatively, you can use [Google Maps API](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

The main differences are you don't have to figure out how to scrape complex Javascript-driven websites, don't think about how to solve CAPTCHA (if it appears), or finding proxies (if they're needed). Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_maps&q=central%20hong%20kong%20bar&ll=%4040.7455096%2C-74.0083012%2C14z&hl=en&type=search).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "type": "search",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "q": "central hong kong bar",
  "hl": "en",
  "ll": "@22.2822068,114.1511132,16z"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['local_results']:
    bar_name = result['title']
    print(bar_name)
```

Output:

```
Quinary
COA
001
The Old Man
ROOM 309
ORIGIN gin bar
The Envoy
Wahtiki Island Lounge
The China Bar, Lan Kwai Fong
The Iron Fairies Hong Kong
Captain's Bar
Le Boudoir
Bar De Luxe
Please Don't Tell
Owl Lounge HK
Tell Camellia Cocktail Bar
HONI HONI Tiki Cocktail Lounge
J.Boroski
Frank's Library
Geronimo Shot Bar HK
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 3):

Google is a very complex search engine, it cannot simply be scraped with a single get request, it also has anti-bot tampering features to prevent people from scraping the site (as Google wants developers to pay for there API and use that instead). Here is a google search module I wrote in python for a project I was working on.

Requests sent through this code will be accepted by the Google server, because it simulates the behavior of a real web browser. By sending a GET request with a User-Agent header, and also generates the necessary cookies.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, os
import datetime

class google_search():
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
        self.url = "https://www.google.co.uk"
        self.domain = ".google.co.uk"
        self.output_filename = "output.html"
        self.write_2_file = False
        self.return_content = True

    def search(self, query):
        # generate header
        self.head =  {
            "User-Agent": self.user_agent,
        }

        # generate cookies
        self.current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.todays_date = self.current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%S")
        self.date_in_month = datetime.datetime(
            self.current_date.year,
            self.current_date.month+1,
            self.current_date.day-1,
            self.current_date.hour,
            self.current_date.minute,
            self.current_date.second
        ).strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        
        self.expiry_date = f"expires={self.date_in_month} GMT"
        self.consent_cookie_fname = "YES+cb.{self.current_date.strftime('%Y%m%d-%m-p0')}.en+FX+949"
        self.cookie = {
            "1P_JAR" : f"={self.todays_date}; {self.expiry_date}; path=/; domain={self.domain}; Secure; SameSite=none",
            "CONSENT" : f"{self.consent_cookie_fname}; Domain={self.domain}; {self.expiry_date}; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=none"
        }

        # send request
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.res = requests.get(f"{self.url}{query}", headers=self.head, cookies=self.cookie)
        html = self.res.content

        # write to file
        if self.write_2_file == True:
            with open(self.output_filename, "wb") as file:
                file.write(html)
                
        elif self.return_content == True:
            return html

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=bar%20hong%20kong%20central&biw=1246&bih=714&sz=16&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALeKk02B3dHjl422M1wOkUldNgdUeC6RVA%3A1621869556252&ei=9MOrYMzsDobZ-QbhyK6YDA&oq=bar+hong+kong+central&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.2313.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.vxIZeVhM24g&tbs=lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e16!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9&rlst=f#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:[[22.287261599999997,114.1668826],[22.2769662,114.1507584]];tbs:lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e16!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9"

req = google_search()
req.url = url
html = req.search("")
```

You can checkout the full code on my GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/JaredTurck/google-search-scraper).

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider that Google is pretty restrictive when it comes to automated requests to its services not via means of supplied APIs and so on. Try to run the example, and then print the `title` of the html you get, it probably will be

> Before proceeding to Google Search

So, that's why you get empty list, since the page you getting in the script is not the same one you get in the browser (probably full of Google's cookies and well known to the system).

You will need to consider some real person behavior and configurations spoofing when work with Google in this way, i.e. user-agent and so forth.